# Ruby compiler for mac?

Tags: ruby, compiler-construction

so I made a program in ruby (using FXRuby as well if that changes anything) and I was wondering how I would compile it so that another person could download and use the program? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to compile it you can just run it as a ruby script,

start your file with #!/path/to/your/ruby/interpreter/bin 
after changing it to the appropriate file and it should just launch from the command line

```
$ chmod +x ./my_ruby_script
$ ./my_ruby_script
```

However if you are devloping a full fledged application in ruby for the mac then consider using [MacRuby](http://macruby.org) which provides ruby-cocoa bridge. It can be found here

Answer (score 0):

Ruby is interpreted, not compiled.  The code itself will be what runs on another person's computer, provided they have a Ruby interpreter.

A quick Google search, however, turned up [this](http://www.erikveen.dds.nl/rubyscript2exe/).  I've never used it, but it's an interesting idea.  Basically it wraps the Ruby application code with the executable(s) and library(s) needed to run it into one single all-encompassing application.